# Principal Component Analysis (PCA) for non-continuous numerical data

Tags: pca, pcamixdata

I am learning PCA and the question is the following: can be PCA applied to a dataset containing both numerical continuous and numerical discrete variables?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to you to read this question: [link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/5774/can-principal-component-analysis-be-applied-to-datasets-containing-a-mix-of-cont)

In my opinion it offers many valuable insights to study this method.